# Circuit analysis of a emitter follower with bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

I'm trying to analyse the circuit below (from Art of Electronics, 2nd edition, p. 96). What are the small signal input and output impedance of this emitter follower?
[image: emitter follower with bootstrap]

I can analyse an emitter follower, but I'm doing something wrong with the capacitor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I would work out the input impedance.

At the frequencies of interest, consider C2 to be a wire.

Note then, that the output voltage appears at the bottom of R3 whilst the input voltage appears at the top.

Let the voltage gain of this circuit be \$A_{CC} < 1\$.

Then the voltage across R3 is \$v_{in} - A_{CC}\ v_{in} = v_{in}(1 - A_{CC})\$

The current through R3 is then \$\dfrac{v_{in}(1 - A_{CC})}{R_3} \$

Thus, to the input voltage source, R3 "looks" bigger by factor of \$\dfrac{1}{1 - A_{CC}} \$

Looking into the base of Q1, the impedance is approximately \$(1 + \beta)\ (R_4||R_2||R_1 + r_e) \$ where \$r_e = \frac{V_T}{I_E} \$.

Then, the input impedance is:

\$r_{in} = \dfrac{R_3}{1 - A_{CC}} || \left[(1 + \beta)\ (R_4||R_2||R_1 + r_e) \right] \$

Since the left hand term in the parallel combination is typically far larger than the right hand term, the input impedance is dominated by the right hand term, i.e.,

\$r_{in} \approx (1 + \beta)\ (R_4||R_2||R_1 + r_e)\$

For example, with \$V_T = 25mV\$ and \$I_E = 1mA\$, \$r_e = 25 \Omega \$ thus, with \$R_4||R_2||R_1 = 833 \Omega \$:

\$r_{in} \approx (1 + \beta)\ 858 \Omega \$

Comment: Thanks, I redid the calculation with yours as guide. I get a slightly different answer: \$r_in = (1+β)(R4||R2||R1) + r_e\$, because \$I_c\$ doesn't go through \$r_e\$. Could you check your calculations just to be sure that there is no wrong information in the answer.

Comment: Instead of relying on the gain you could also put \$R_3 \text{ parallel to } r_e\$, \$R_3\$ is much bigger than  \$r_e\$ so \$ r^{'}_{e} \approx r_e\$.

Comment: @Henk, you may be thinking about \$r_\pi\$ rather than \$r_e\$:  \$r_\pi = (1 + \beta)r_e\$

Comment: You're right, I only knew of the Hybrid-\$\pi\$ model.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I have a question. How did you determine that the amplified \$R_3\$ is paralleled by the other impedance block?

Comment: @OFRBG, the impedance looking into the base is in parallel with the impedance looking into R3.

Answer (score 1):

There is a text on this question for your reference:

https://archive.cnx.org/contents/47311555-728f-4d1d-a5c1-2138ff7e604c@1/ae-lecture5-partd-bootstrapping-and-darlington-pair

The key improvement over non-bootstraped version is to allow much higher input impedance.